# Recuperar dados do localStorage em seu determinado input!

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Tenho um código que cadastra dinamicamente, os dados dos inputs no localStorage.

Estou tentando recuperar os dados cadastrados em seus respectivos inputs, mas sem sucesso.

Esse é o código para recuperar os dados, mas só recupera o primeiro dado cadastrado:

```
$("#exibir").click(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){  
        var inputs = $('input[type="text"]');
      inputs.val(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
  }
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/guilhermelirio85/vvjobh19/)

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema não é com o `localStorage`, essa parte do código está perfeita. O problema é com sua variável `inputs`. Porque `$('input[type="text"]')` retorna um array com todos os `<inputs>` de tipo `text`, e portanto, você está chamando o método `.val()` em um array de elementos.

```
[ <input>, <input>, <input> ].val("9001");  // Não vai funcionar!
```

Você precisa iterar por todos os elementos no seu array `inputs` e, para cada um, chamar o `.val()`.

Comment: Eu modifiquei ontem mesmo e acabei conseguindo:

`$("#exibir").on('click', function() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var inputs = $('input[id="' + id + '"]');
    inputs.val(localStorage.getItem(id));
  });
})`

Comment: Ah sim, com `.each()`. É isso ai! :D